# Python Beautiful Soup retrieving old data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to Beautiful Soup, i am retrieving information from the following page https://www.virginmedia.com/broadband/broadband-only.

Its retrieving the data as I need but now I have noticed its not pulling down the most current data even though I can see its been updated in my browser.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.3 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
}
page = requests.get('https://www.virginmedia.com/broadband/broadband-only') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# setup fee

setupCosts = soup.find_all("p", class_="price-container ng-star-inserted")

for setupCost in setupCosts:
    print (setupCost.string)

 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee 
 £0 set up fee
```

Comment: you may have the most common problem: page may use `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`, `requests` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`. OR you may try to use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` read data from other URL, And then you could try to use `requests` to also read data from this url. Usually Javascritp get data as JSON which can be simply converted to Python dictionary and it doesn't need `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: I think you maybe right.  It looks like the site is running Angular using GraphQL.  The graphql response looks like its pulling down a lot more than what is required to display that page and it doesn't look like it will be easy to pull out the bits I need.